# Auto increasing JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I want to output text from a .txt file which will have more and more text, however if I do that without modifying the size of the JLabel, the text just goes off screen, is it possible to somehow auto increase a JLabel while somehow detecting how much more is needed to increase to fill all of the text? Or is there any other text holder which is not editable but would fulfill that need?

Comment: Use [**JList**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) instead lables.

Comment: 1- Use a non-editable `JTextArea` 2- Wrap the text in html

Comment: depends on your exact requirement/context - be precise when describing the problem (and how it should behave), best with a SSCCE

Comment: @Azad , I guess I wasn't clear enough, however I do not need any kind of list, only simple text going on and on. MadProgrammer thank you very much for the contribution. kleopatra , I'm sorry, I simply had nothing more to add, it is in planning phase and I did mention I wanted text, no list no nothing, which keeps being added from a .txt file, all of that can be understood as simple methods. The needed thing was that I would have the ability to increase the size of the label as the text increases so I don't go more then it and not see the text. It was all from a logic standpoint,thank you tho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make any [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html) Component with a [Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) non-editable, so you´re free to choose. Choosing something that can be nicely wrapped in [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html), like the mentioned [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) or [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html), is a good choice.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will accept the answer because of the awesome documentation

Answer (score 1):

Although a variable sized JLabel is probably not good UI style, you could achieve the desired functionality by putting the JLabel in an appropriate layout manager and requesting a new layout. How to force a new layout is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761374/force-immediate-layout-and-paint-in-swing).

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable {
                             public void run() { 
                                somecomponent.repaint();
                             }
                           });
```

Comment: revalidate() do that, code line with repaint() is required to add in some cases

Answer (score 1):

Use Text Area if you have long text.
Its not advisable to have auto increasing length of components. Because alignments of your 
other components on screen may suffer.

For these type of situations we rely on **scrollBar**.

So therefore. Use TextArea, set a **preferredSize** for them. and Then Use ScollBar if text
goes out of Preferred Size.

Another Solution : Decide Min and Max Size for your component. Default display 
will show text in Min Size. If text increases, then increase size of text Area. 
Stop increasing size till it hits Max size. Show scrollBars if it hits max. 
Remember for this you might have to override JTextArea or its UIComponent(preferred).

Comment: on the verge of downvoting for [setXXSize - don't, ever](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229519/203657) JTextArea has api to set its preferred size in terms of rows/columns, a suitable LayoutManager will handle any further fine-tuning if needed

Comment: @kleopatra i agree. And i think I mentioned preferredSize Only (made it bold) . But if you use custom ComponentUI, you are in very much control of your component and you can use  these values judiciously. ComponentUI handles the main responsiblity for rendering the component. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/ComponentUI.html