# How to force repaint in Swing while debugging?

Tags: java, swing, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm using Swing and while debugging, I would like to redraw the whole frame to help me understand what's going on. I can perfectly look at my local variables with my debugger but nothing is like visual feedback. How can I force a frame/panel to repaint itself?

I don't care how dirty/unappropriate for real applications the solution is, I just want to execute that with my debugger's expression evaluator while I'm debugging. Since the `repaint()` method seems to do nothing but to add a event to the event queue, it is not working when my debugging pauses my application. I feel like I will need to make the EventQueue or UI thread update itself but I don't know how.

I would like to have a solution to repaint while I'm in the EventQueue thread but also interested to know what's different if I'm in another thread. I'm debugging using IntelliJ Idea.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761374/force-immediate-layout-and-paint-in-swing , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120528/repaint-in-a-loop , etc. perhaps. YMMV.

Comment: @user2864740 Indeed, `paintImmediatley()` did the job